# For each div create a div and set links by finding source of current div image

Tags: html, jquery

I want to achieve this functionality with jQuery:

alot of divs are there in html with class name `.separator` they all contains images wrapped with anchor tags. What i want to do is add two buttons for download and large preview (which is done in current code) but i want to set their url from current image's source.

**THE HTML:**

```
<!-- indefinite divs like this one with different source and links -->
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://example.com/1920x1080.jpg">
     <img alt="my image" src="https://example.com/1920x1080.jpg" width="640" />
   </a>
</div>
```

**THE JQUERY (PARTIALLY WORKING):**

```
$('.separator').each(function(){
    //fetch the source of image using find
    var imgsrc = $(this).find('img').attr('src');

    //needs to set the above variable in below tags

    //anchor tags added for each image without any href attribute
    $(this).append('<div class="row mt-2 mb-2 mx-auto bg-light imglinks"><a href="" class="btn btn-success">Download</a> <a href="" class="btn btn-link">View Large</a></div>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a "download" attribute on a download `a href`

and the link variable `' + imgsrc + '` for url to the image

*The reason that the download button will not show dialog window in this example is: [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). When the photos are from the same domain as the website ... the dialog box will work*

```js
$('.separator').each(function () {
    var imgsrc = $(this).find('img').attr('src');

    $(this).append('<div class="row mt-2 mb-2 mx-auto bg-light imglinks"><a href="' + imgsrc + '" download class="btn btn-success">Download</a> <a href="' + imgsrc + '" class="btn btn-link">View Large</a></div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- indefinite divs like this one with different source and links -->
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://blog.54ka.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/horses-on-summer-meadow_027_by_54ka.jpg">
        <img alt="my image"
            src="https://blog.54ka.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/horses-on-summer-meadow_027_by_54ka.jpg"
            width="640" />
    </a>
</div>
```